# WP7: How to save and restore a list box as image in phone memory

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, memory

In my windows phone application i have a listbox with some data in it that i want to save as image in phone memory.  Actually user can update the listbox and should be able to save the current list of data. I thought about capturing the listbox as image and save it in phone memory. I have done this in objective-c but I'm not sure if it's possible in c#. I found the following code and tried it to save my listbox:

```
public static void SaveToMediaLibrary(FrameworkElement element,string title)
    {
        try
        {
            var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(element, null);
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            bmp.SaveJpeg(ms, (int)element.ActualWidth,
                        (int)element.ActualHeight,
                        0, 100);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var lib = new MediaLibrary();
            var filePath = string.Format(title + ".jpg");
            lib.SavePicture(filePath, ms);
            MessageBox.Show("Saved!",
                            "Done",
                            MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error.",
                "Cannot save", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }
```

And called it with:

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //CalculationList is the listbox
        SaveToMediaLibrary(CalcultionList, "saveTest");
    }
```

The problem is that i can't open the file to see if it's saved correctly(I'm debugging on emulator). Can someone tell me how can I open the saved file. Or if it's not possible at least tell me what i am doing is correct or not.
I've just started WP dev. I searched through MSDN samples but I can't find what I want.

Comment: What do you mean you can't open the file? If you're saving the file to the media library, all you have to do is open the Pictures and check if the file is there! I know that there isn't a shortcut for the Pictures in the emulator, but you can always just use a PhotoChooserTask to open it up and check if the picture is there!

Comment: thanks, i didn't know about this solution as i mentioned i'm a noob in WP dev. I'll have a look in the documentation for chooser.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider to use the [Use the Isolated Storage Explorer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) ?

If the image is saved at isolated storage then you may see and "download" it to your PC.

Cheers,

josemiguel